# Map does not show the location button after first time start fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

> I have a map fragment named `TestMap`.When it loaded  first
>   time, it  show current location and location button from method
>   `setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true)`. When it loaded after first
>   time it not show current location and location button .........
>              Any idea why?

TestMap...

```
 package com.example.map;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestMap extends Fragment{
    public  GoogleMap gmap;
    View view;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.findmap, container, false);
        initializemap();
        gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // gmap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        return view;
    }

    private void initializemap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(gmap == null){
            gmap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView))
                    .getMap();
        }
        if (gmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }   
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        // initializemap();
    }

    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        if (f != null){ 
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setMyLocationButtonEnabled()` is true by default.

```
     // Show current location    
        gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     //  Location button
     //comment this line gmap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```